# Concurrent processing service

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have method that gets called from different processes, sometimes concurrently. Somewhere within that method I'm suppose to calculate discount. For this, I've created a DiscountService that reads info from DB and calculates a discount for a given customer number. As mentioned above, the main method may be called from different locations with different customer number simultaneously.

**Main Method:**

```
// this may be called simultaneously
public void Handle(IDocument document)
{
  // document contains customer number
  ...
  // update document discount property
  this._discountService.Process(document);
  // continue processing
```

**DiscountService:**

```
public class DiscountService : IDiscountService
{
    private readonly IDiscountDataAccess discountDataAccess;

    private readonly ILog logger;

    public DiscountService(ILog logger, IDiscountDataAccess discountDataAccess)
    {
        this.discountDataAccess = discountDataAccess;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Process(IDiscountDocument discountDocument)
    {
        this.ProcessDiscount(discountDocument);
        discountDocument.Update();
    }

    private void ProcessDiscount(IDiscountDocument discountDocument)
    {
        Discount discount = this.GetAvailableDiscount(discountDocument);
        ...
    }
    private Discount GetAvailableDiscount(IDiscountDocument discountDocument)
    {
        // Stored proc 
        return this.discountDataAccess.GetAvailableDiscount(
            discountDocument.CustomerNumber, 
            discountDocument.StartDate, 
            discountDocument.EndDate);
    }
    ...
}
```

My question is that should my DiscountService be thread safe? If so how would I do it for this situation. Or would I need some type of manager that would "new" DiscountService for each main method call? Or this sufficient?

thanks

EDIT:
Is there a pattern for doing things like this. Having ONE service that would operate (simultaneously)?

**Is there a book, pluralsight videos that talks about the designs/patterns of stuff like this? gives examples?**

Comment: It depends, is `GetAvailableDiscount` thread safe already (does it not use any external state)? if so DiscountService is already thread safe assuming the passed in `IDiscountDocument ` is only used by one thread at a time or is also thread safe on `.Update()`. We need more information to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: When Handle() receives a document, I pass that reference to DiscountService (which in turn is passed around to IT's private methods)..so the reference still points to same original document. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And to address your update with more info, it all depends on if `discountDataAccess` is thread safe or not. If it is you don't need to change anything, if it is not you need to handle it (This is basically what [Martin is saying](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29101652/80274))

Comment: BUT if in my DiscountService I had a private IDiscountDocument that would be passed via constructor - then I would need thread safety. correct?

Comment: Martin is saying to lock the discountDocument it is pretty obvious that discountDataAccess.GetAvailableDiscount need locking. discountDocument only needs locking if that instance is shared between all those callers of handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if you a reading some stuff from the DB for a given ID, and from the data you retrieve you can calculate everything you need, then there is no need for thread-safety as you don't have a shared memory access.

What's not clear from your post is whether or not the provided discountDocument is accessed from multiple threads, or if it just lives for the time out the request processing.

From what I can see, I would assume that the discountDocument needs to be made thread-safe (within the object, but this is just a guess as I don't know what else happens to it), but the service is fine as-is.

Comment: For example: Handle(IDocument document) may be called 10 times at the same time, that's 10 instances of IDocument. IDocument has a method Update() that pretty much sets a "discount" property to whatever discount service calculated. Is there a need for thread safety if they're 10 different instances of IDocument?

Comment: the problem is not in the document but in discountDataAccess.GetAvailableDiscount

Comment: Is there a book, pluralsight videos that talks about the designs/patterns of stuff like this? gives examples?

Answer (score 1):

From your code you are doing dependency injection with discountDataAccess :

```
public DiscountService(ILog logger, IDiscountDataAccess discountDataAccess)
{
    this.discountDataAccess = discountDataAccess;
    this.logger = logger;
}
```

then later you make use of this injected service like here :

```
private Discount GetAvailableDiscount(IDiscountDocument discountDocument)
{
    // Stored proc 
    return this.discountDataAccess.GetAvailableDiscount(
        discountDocument.CustomerNumber, 
        discountDocument.StartDate, 
        discountDocument.EndDate);
}
```

So for me the conclusion is that the discountDataAccess must be made thread safe or at least the getavailablediscount in particular. The chance is very high that you are either going to create or reuse an existing connection and if there is not protection mechanism will run into problems.

DiscountDocument comes in via the request and I am assuming there is a different document per request, so the problem is not likely in DiscountDocument.

If however the discountDocument is indeed also a shared resource, then it might need some locking of its own and then problems get bigger and bigger because you run the risk of having a deadlock in that situation.

Comment: so put a lock in GetAvailableDiscount or outside it?